# Java: ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de convertir una tarea en multihilo?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, hilos

Tengo hecho un programa en Java para rodar copias de seguridad de unas bases de datos en SQL Server. **El programa es sencillo pero hace las copias una detrás de otra**.

Os dejo la implementación en Java:

```
/**
 * Método que hace copia de seguridad de las bases de datos indicadas de un
 * host destino sobre un directorio remoto.
 *
 * @param db_connect_string Host que contiene la base de datos a la que nos
 * queremos conectar. Ejemplo: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100
 * @param db_userid Usuario con el que nos conectamos. Normalmente será 'sa'
 * @param db_password Contraseña del usuario
 * @param db_names Array de Strings con las bases de datos de las que
 * haremos copia
 * @param remoteDirectory Directorio del host donde queremos dejar los
 * ficheros de copia, ha de existir para que no falle
 */
public static void databasesBackup(String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password, String db_names[], String remoteDirectory) {
    try {
        // Conectamos con la base de datos
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
        System.out.printf("INFO: Conectado con éxito a '%s' con el usuario '%s'.\n", db_connect_string, db_userid);

        // Informamos al usuario de las bases de datos que van a ser copiadas
        System.out.printf("INFO: Se va a hacer copia en el directorio remoto '%s' de las siguientes bases de datos:\n", remoteDirectory);
        for (String db_name : db_names) {
            System.out.println(db_name);
        }

        // Invocamos el script de copia: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        String backupSQL
                = "DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)\n"
                + "DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256)\n"
                + "DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256)\n"
                + "DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20)\n"
                + "SET @path = '" + remoteDirectory + "'\n"
                + "SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)\n";

        // Lanzamos la copia
        System.out.printf("INFO: Lanzada copia, por favor espere:\n");
        for (String db_name : db_names) {
            System.out.printf("Copiando '%s'... ", db_name);

            String tempSQL
                    = backupSQL
                    + "SET @fileName = @path + '" + db_name + "' + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'\n"
                    + "BACKUP DATABASE " + db_name + " TO DISK = @fileName\n";
            s.execute(tempSQL);

            System.out.println("¡Copiada!");
        }

        System.out.println("INFO: ¡Copia finalizada!");
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        // Si falla algo, lo indicaremos por consola
        System.out.printf("ERROR: Se ha producido una excepción a la hora de ejecutar el SQL:\n");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    }
}
```

**Imaginemos que quiero hacer copia de dos o más bases de datos a la vez, de tal manera que** si la base de datos A tarda 2 minutos y la B 30 segundos, en vez de tardar en total 2 minutos y medio, **las copias se lancen en paralelo** y tarde algo menos.

**¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacer este esquema multihilo?** Me valdría con un esqueleto de una aplicación que ya lo sea, aunque nada tenga que ver con este cometido.

Gracias por adelantado, saludos.

**EDITO**:

Al final lo resolví usando un objeto de la clase [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Así es como quedó.

Clase *TareaCopiaSQLServer*:

```
package sql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Clase TareaCopiaSQLServer.
 *
 * @author Antonio A. López Fernández
 * @version 31/08/2017
 */
public class TareaCopiaSQLServer implements Runnable {

    // Atributos:
    private String db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password, db_name, remoteDirectory;

    /**
     * Constructor del hilo TareaCopia.
     *
     * @param db_connect_string Host que contiene la base de datos a la que nos
     * queremos conectar. Ejemplo: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100
     * @param db_userid Usuario con el que nos conectamos. Normalmente será 'sa'
     * @param db_password Contraseña del usuario
     * @param db_name Nombre de la base de datos de la cual haremos copia
     * @param remoteDirectory Directorio del host donde queremos dejar los
     * ficheros de copia, ha de existir para que no falle
     */
    public TareaCopiaSQLServer(String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password, String db_name, String remoteDirectory) {
        this.db_connect_string = db_connect_string;
        this.db_userid = db_userid;
        this.db_password = db_password;
        this.db_name = db_name;
        this.remoteDirectory = remoteDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Conectamos con la base de datos
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

            // Informamos al usuario de la base de datos que va a ser copiada
            System.out.printf("INFO: Se va a hacer copia en el directorio remoto '%s' de la base de datos '%s'.\n", remoteDirectory, db_name);

            // Invocamos el script de copia: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            String backupSQL
                    = "DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)\n"
                    + "DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256)\n"
                    + "DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256)\n"
                    + "DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20)\n"
                    + "SET @path = '" + remoteDirectory + "'\n"
                    + "SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)\n";

            // Lanzamos la copia
            System.out.printf("INFO: Lanzada copia de '%s', por favor espere...\n", db_name);
            String tempSQL
                    = backupSQL
                    + "SET @fileName = @path + '" + db_name + "' + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'\n"
                    + "BACKUP DATABASE " + db_name + " TO DISK = @fileName\n";
            s.execute(tempSQL);

            System.out.printf("INFO: Copia de la base de datos '%s' finalizada.\n", db_name);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            // Si falla algo, lo indicaremos por consola
            System.out.printf("ERROR: Se ha producido una excepción a la hora de ejecutar el SQL:\n");
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Clase *Main*:

```
package sql;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * Programa principal.
 *
 * @author Antonio A. López Fernández
 * @version 31/08/2017
 */
public class Main {

    // Atributos:
    private static final int MAX_HILOS = 2;

    /**
     * Método main.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Creamos las tareas
        Runnable bd1 = new TareaCopiaSQLServer("jdbc:sqlserver://13.12.11.10", "sa", "P4s5w0rD", "PericoElDeLosPalotes", "C:\\COPIAS\\SQL\\");
        Runnable bd2 = new TareaCopiaSQLServer("jdbc:sqlserver://13.12.11.10", "sa", "P4s5w0rD", "PepeElGamuzas", "C:\\COPIAS\\SQL\\");
        Runnable bd3 = new TareaCopiaSQLServer("jdbc:sqlserver://13.12.11.10", "sa", "P4s5w0rD", "JuanElMazorco", "C:\\COPIAS\\SQL\\");

        // Creamos el pool de threads
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_HILOS);

        // Asociamos las tareas con el pool, lanzándolas
        pool.execute(bd1);
        pool.execute(bd2);
        pool.execute(bd3);

        // Paramos el pool
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

*Salida* (obviamente, IP's y nombres inventados):

```
INFO: Se va a hacer copia en el directorio remoto 'C:\COPIAS\SQL\' de la base de datos 'PericoElDeLosPalotes'.
INFO: Se va a hacer copia en el directorio remoto 'C:\COPIAS\SQL\' de la base de datos 'PepeElGamuzas'.
INFO: Lanzada copia de 'PepeElGamuzas', por favor espere...
INFO: Lanzada copia de 'PericoElDeLosPalotes', por favor espere...
INFO: Copia de la base de datos 'PericoElDeLosPalotes' finalizada.
INFO: Se va a hacer copia en el directorio remoto 'C:\COPIAS\SQL\' de la base de datos 'JuanElMazorco'.
INFO: Lanzada copia de 'JuanElMazorco', por favor espere...
INFO: Copia de la base de datos 'PepeElGamuzas' finalizada.
INFO: Copia de la base de datos 'JuanElMazorco' finalizada.
```

Comment: He encontrado este [enlace](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/thread-pools-java/), ¿podría ser un buen punto de partida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo crea un hilo por cada base de datos que quieras hacer el backup con la clase `Thread`.

Modifique tu codigo agregandole un callback para saber cuando la copia del backup termino o fallo y asi estar mas al tanto del progreso de cada backup.

Defins esta interfaz en tu proyecto:

```
public interface OnBackupFinishedListener
{
  void succes(String dbName);
  void failed(String database, Exception e);
}
```

Este es el metodo modificado. Fijate que por cada db crea un hilo nuevo:

```
public static void databasesBackup(String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password, String db_names[], String remoteDirectory, OnBackupFinishedListener finisListener) {


 for(String db_name : db_names)
 {
      new Thread(new Runnable(){

       @Override
       public void run(){

               try {

                    // Conectamos con la base de datos
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
                    System.out.printf("INFO: Conectado con éxito a '%s' con el usuario '%s'.\n", db_connect_string, db_userid);

                    // Informamos al usuario de las bases de datos que van a ser copiadas
                    System.out.printf("INFO: Se va a hacer copia en el directorio remoto '%s' de las siguientes bases de datos:\n", remoteDirectory);
                    for (String db_name : db_names) {
                        System.out.println(db_name);
                    }

                    // Invocamos el script de copia: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/
                    Statement s = c.createStatement();
                    String backupSQL
                            = "DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)\n"
                            + "DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256)\n"
                            + "DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256)\n"
                            + "DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20)\n"
                            + "SET @path = '" + remoteDirectory + "'\n"
                            + "SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)\n";

                    // Lanzamos la copia
                    System.out.printf("INFO: Lanzada copia, por favor espere:\n");

                    System.out.printf("Copiando '%s'... ", db_name);

                    String tempSQL
                            = backupSQL
                            + "SET @fileName = @path + '" + db_name + "' + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'\n"
                            + "BACKUP DATABASE " + db_name + " TO DISK = @fileName\n";
                    s.execute(tempSQL);

                    System.out.println("¡Copiada!");


                    System.out.println("INFO: ¡Copia finalizada!");
                    finisListener.success(db_name);
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                // Si falla algo, lo indicaremos por consola
                System.out.printf("ERROR: Se ha producido una excepción a la hora de ejecutar el SQL:\n");
                sqle.printStackTrace();

                finisListener.failed(db_name, sqle); // notificamos fallo
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                finisListener.failed(db_name, ex); // notificamos fallo
            }

       }
     }).run();
 }

}
```

Entonces este seria el uso:

```
 databasesBackup("db_connect_string", "db_userid", "db_password", new String[...], "remoteDirectory", new OnBackupFinishedListener(){
  @Override
  public void success(String dbName)
  {
     System.out.print("Backup exitoso de base de datos: " + dbName);
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(String dbName, Exception error)
  {
     System.out.println("Fallo backup db: " + dbName);
     error.printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

Comment: Gracias, hice algo muy parecido. Añado la respuesta a mi propia pregunta.